# XAML live preview is not available

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winui-3

I'm trying to build a WinUI3 application with C++, and it seems to no xaml live preview is available while I'm debugging the app. How to fix it? Thanks a lot. By the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community 17.8.

[image]

There will be a xaml live preview window.

Answer (score 0):

The XAML Live Preview window is available **during debugging**.

To open it, go to `Debug` > `Windows` > `XAML Live Preview`.
[image]

Or, select the Show in XAML Live Preview button in the application toolbar.

[image]